# jquery fancybox - prevent close on click outside of fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, fancybox

I'm using the [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) plugin for my modal windows.  It seems like no matter what options I use I can't prevent the fancybox modal window from closing when the user clicks outside of the fancybox modal window (grayed out area).

Is there a way to force the user to click the X or a button that I trigger the close event?  This seems like it should be simple so I'm hoping I'm just reading the examples wrong.

I've tried `hideOnContentClick: false` but that doesn't seem to be working for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: It works on that site link you gave, you got any code?

Comment: Right, but on all of the examples if you click outside of the modal window it closes.  I want it to remain open unless the user clicks the X (no where else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option for that. You will have to change the source code.

In jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js you need to comment out (or delete) line 341 in the _finish method:

```
//$("#fancy_overlay, #fancy_close").bind("click", $.fn.fancybox.close);
```

Comment: Excellent.  I commented the line out and added:

$("#fancy_close).bind("click", $.fn.fancybox.close);

This does exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: there is an option as in cool_dev answer below, editing the code will lead to problems when you need to update, your changes will be over-written

Comment: how did you read the file . there is a method to convert minified Js ?

Answer (score 23):

```
   jQuery(".lightbox").fancybox({
        helpers     : {
            overlay : {
                speedIn  : 0,
                speedOut : 300,
                opacity  : 0.8,
                css      : {
                    cursor : 'default'
                },
                closeClick: false
            }
        },
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't actually answers the original question, which uses fancybox v1.2.1. For versions between v1.2.6 and v1.3.4 see @cool_dev's answer. For fancybox 2.x see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987

Answer (score 11):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your_link").fancybox({
      'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
      'hideOnContentClick':false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm using fancybox 1.3.1, if you wanna force the user to close the modal box ONLY by clicking on the button, you can specify in the configuration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your_link").fancybox({
      'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
      'hideOnContentClick':false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked using fancybox 1.3.4

Answer (score 6):

For this issue, please try this way

```
$("YourElement").fancybox({
 helpers: {
        overlay: { closeClick: false } //Disable click outside event
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this doesn't actually answers the original question, which uses fancybox v1.2.1. For versions between v1.2.6 and v1.3.4 see @cool_dev's answer. For fancybox 2.x see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987

Comment: @JKF: Thanks I will improved my knowledge

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Fancybox 1.2.6 (like I am on a project), I found out the option hideOnOverlayClick. You can set it to false (e.g. hideOnOverlayClick: false).

I found this option while exploring to modify the code based on the suggestion givn by Scott Dowding.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same "issue". This worked for me:

```
$("#fancybox-overlay").unbind();
```

Comment: for version 2.1.4 they can change this to $(".fancybox-overlay").unbind();

Answer (score 3):

none of the above worked for me, so i just wrote a simple bit for latest version of fancybox.

```
function load(parameters) {
    $('.fancybox-outer').after('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:{parent.$.fancybox.close();}" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" title="Close"></a>');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".various").fancybox({ 
        modal: true,
        afterLoad: load
    });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The `$("#fancybox-overlay").unbind()` solution given for this question by @Gabriel works except I needed to bind it to the fancybox after it loads its content, and I couldn't unbind immediately. For anyone who runs into this issue, the following code solved the problem for me:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({'afterLoad' : function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#fancybox-overlay").unbind(); }, 400);}
});
```

The 400ms delay got it working for me. It worked with 300ms but I didn't want to take chances.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `closeClick` parameter to **false** inside your function:

```
$(".video").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        width: 640,
        height: 385,
        helpers: { 
            overlay: {
                closeClick: false
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: please don't shout, especially not in **Bold** :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add following line to your function, you do not have to change anything in  jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.js

```
callbackOnStart : function() {$("#fancy_overlay").bind("click","null");},
```

Comment: We only wanted this behavior on one of our fancy boxes so changing the source wasn't an option, Thanks!

Comment: Just discovered that this doesn't work on Google Chrome, haven't figured out why yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent the fancy box to close by applying these setting

```
 'showCloseButton'=>false, // hide close button from fancybox
 'hideOnOverlayClick'=>false, // outside of fancybox click disabled
 'enableEscapeButton'=>false, // disable close on escape key press
```

get the fancybox setting from following link

http://www.fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a combination of all of the above answers, as all of them include errors.  Certainly, no editing of the source code is necessary.

In my case, I wanted to disable overlay clicks closing the box as I had a progression of questions that would be displayed sequentially inside the fancybox, so I didn't want users to lose their progress by accidentally clicking on the overlay, but wanted to keep that functionality elsewhere on the page.

Use this to disable it:

```
$(".fancybox-overlay").unbind();
```

Use this to re-enable it:

```
$(".fancybox-overlay").bind("click", $.fancybox.close);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#Mypopup").fancybox({
        "hideOnOverlayClick" : false, // prevents closing clicking OUTSIE fancybox
        "hideOnContentClick" : false, // prevents closing clicking INSIDE fancybox
        "enableEscapeButton" : false  // prevents closing pressing ESCAPE key
  });
  $("a#Mypopup").trigger('click');
});

<a id="Mypopup" href="images/popup.png"><img alt="Mypopup" src="images/popup.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the default closeClick on the overlay to false. Has worked for me in version 2.1.5.

```
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.defaults.closeClick=false;
```