# jquery fancybox 2.0.3 - prevent close on click outside of fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox version 2.0.3. I want to prevent close on click outside of fancybox. I want to force user to click the cross button. I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        hideOnOverlayClick:false,
        hideOnContentClick:false
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

but this doesn't seems to work in new version of fancybox. I had referred the link

[jquery fancybox - prevent close on click outside of fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363806/jquery-fancybox-prevent-close-on-click-outside-of-fancybox)

but these solutions doesn't seems to work in fancybox 2.0.3

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use this option:

```
helpers : { 
  overlay : {closeClick: false}
}
```

so your final script should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".various").fancybox({
  closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox 
  openEffect  : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  helpers   : { 
   overlay : {closeClick: false} // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
  }
 }).trigger("click");
});
```

`hideOnOverlayClick` and `hideOnContentClick` are options for Fancybox v1.3.x

Comment: Script works nicely apart from it shows fancybox on document ready, not after I click the relevant button. Any ideas how to prevent that?

Comment: @Pejs if you don't want the script just after the page load, then remove `.trigger("click")` from the code above

Comment: If you are using Fancybox 3, add `clickSlide : false` to your options array.

Comment: fancybox 3.3.1 just needs "clickSlide: false" to prevent closing on side click, just as Ryan Burney mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

The OP asked about fancyBox 2.0, but if you came here looking for an answer and are using fancyBox 3.0+, you can simply do:

```
$('.various').fancybox({
    clickSlide: false, // disable close on outside click
    touch: false // disable close on swipe
});
```

You can also completely disable the close button by adding `smallBtn` and `toolbar` to the options array and setting both to `false`.

Tested with fancyBox 3.5.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").fancybox({
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers   : { 
            overlay : {
                closeClick: false,
            }
        }
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Hi Deepak,

Thanks for your first answer on stackoverflow.  If possible please do explain why an answer works in order to help the community learn more :)

Happy programming...

Sam (reviewer)

Answer (score 0):

Using solution from Vennik - [jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/425](http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/425) .

If you want to prevent click outside.

Use it for example:

```
$(".fancybox_pdf").fancybox({
      helpers : { 
      overlay : {closeClick: false}
      },
      autoSize: false,

        afterShow: function() {
            $(".fancybox-close").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                last.click();
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.refer').fancybox({'width':395,'height':135,'type':'iframe',title:{type:'outside'},'closeBtn':false,helpers:{overlay:{closeClick:false}
}})`[enter link description here](https://www.findinall.com/blogs/jquery-fancybox-%E2%80%A6-outside-disable)