# Fancybox - Implementing afterClose callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

My javascript syntax is rookie-level, but I'm learning :>

I'm using Fancybox 2.1.4 to reveal an inline `<div id="content">`.
Traditionally, the `<div>` would be set to `style="display:none"` and Fancybox will change that to block when activated, and back to `none` when closed.

In my case, I actually have the content of that `<div>` visible on the page in a different location (it's the right thing for the project, I know there are various opinions that can be had there).

So I need to keep `<div id="content">` from disappearing after closing the fancybox (which it natively disappears).

After some research, I found that using the `afterClose` callback, I can simply change or add the inline style of `id"content"` to `display:block` (which solves the problem.

The problem... is my rookiness :>
I tried for quite a long time and just not sure where to put the code, and the right syntax.

How would i add that `afterClose` to my fancybox function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox(
        );
    }); 
</script>
```

Thanks very much for any assist

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Make FancyBox not hide original inline block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163967/how-to-make-fancybox-not-hide-original-inline-block)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the format :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
           afterClose : function(){
             // here any javascript or jQuery to execute after close
           }
        }); // close fancybox
    }); // close ready
</script>
```