# Alternative property for 'hideOnOverlayClick' and 'enableEscapeButton' in fancybox 2.1.4

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am moving from fancybox 1.3.4 to fancybox 2.1.4 , i want alternative property for `hideOnOverlayClick` and `enableEscapeButton` that is available in fancybox 1.3.4 but i am not able to find this two property in fancybox 2.1.4

so any alternative is available  for this two property in fancybox 2.1.4 ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `hideOnOverlayClick` use :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  helpers   : { 
    overlay : { closeClick: false } 
  }
});
```

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987 for further information.

For `enableEscapeButton` use :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  keys : {
    close : null // default value = [27]
  }
});
```

Altogether ?

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  helpers   : { 
    overlay : { closeClick: false } // same as "hideOnOverlayClick" : false, in v1.3.4
  },
  keys : {
    close : null // same as "enableEscapeButton" : false, in v1.3.4
  }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F5z7s/)**