# how to prevent fancybox2 modal from closing until user clicks the actual close button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, fancybox-2

I'm hoping to use Fancybox2 to display a modal edit form for a rails 3.2 application, but if the end user clicks anywhere outside the modal window then fancybox closes.

Is there a way to disable that so the modal will not close (throwing away their edits) if they accidentally click on the underlying web page?

If not, can anyone suggest a simple rails 3.2 gem to implement modal popup form editing?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987

Comment: bingo jfk - worked great - if you add as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: You could just up vote my [referred](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987) answer instead and we vote to close this one as duplicated ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery fancybox 2.0.3 - prevent close on click outside of fancybox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400433/jquery-fancybox-2-0-3-prevent-close-on-click-outside-of-fancybox)