# Fancybox3 with iFrame - prevent close on overlay click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I am using Fancybox3 to open iframe in popup, but I need deny close on click on overlay, because in iframe is form, which user must fill out.

I tried edit outsideClick parameter 'close' to 'false' in fancybox.js and [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400433/jquery-fancybox-2-0-3-prevent-close-on-click-outside-of-fancybox) too, but it's still closing on click on overlay.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Put the code with what you tried, and the errors you are getting. This will help people to help you...

Comment: I dont get any error, the fancybox just close on click to overlay. Code is in attached guide link.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `clickSlide` option. v3 works as a slider and is highly customizable (for example, you can resize and/or reposition sliding area), therefore there is a seperate options for clicking the slide and overlay element.