# fancybox3 Javascript Init iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox-3

I am having issues implementing this solution for my iframe link:
[Fancybox3 with iFrame - prevent close on overlay click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286195/fancybox3-with-iframe-prevent-close-on-overlay-click)

Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My page</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.6/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" href="https://fancyapps.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Test Box</a>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.6/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$.fancybox({
    clickSlide: false
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

All libraries are current, but I can't get the javascript for the clickSlide to work.  Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you aren't waiting for the DOM to load. I would say just put your fancybox initialization inside `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fancybox({
     clickSlide: false
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error, check documentation and use it like this -

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  clickSlide: false
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaYNbr?editors=1010

OR

```
$.fancybox.defaults.clickSlide = false;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEKzaM?editors=1010

AND place your JS code before HTML or wrap inside `$( document ).ready()`