# Disable external click the fancybox popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Disable external click the fancybox popup

How could disable the close button outside the popup div

Using:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the modal true to disable closing when click outsite the modal div

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
            modal :  true
        });
```

Comment: this may help you more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363806/jquery-fancybox-prevent-close-on-click-outside-of-fancybox

Comment: @Raul : the links of reference are outdated, better check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987

Answer (score 1):

```
closeBtn     
  If set to true, close button will be displayed    
  Boolean; Default value: true
```

[read the documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: he meant external click not just to hide the close button. Read again the documentation